# How to listen to INotifyDataErrorInfo using a CollectionView

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, listcollectionview, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have the following scenario:

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lsv_edit_selectNode" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
    Grid.RowSpan="17" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Single" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes.CollectionView, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}">
```

Where Nodes is a custom `ObservableCollection` that contains a ListCollectionView:

```
Public Class FilterableObservableCollection(Of T)
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of T)
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
    Public Property CollectionView As ListCollectionView
        Get
            Return _collectionView
        End Get
        Protected Set(value As ListCollectionView)
            If value IsNot _collectionView Then
                _collectionView = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    'etc.
```

`T` in this case is a `Node` object, with many properties including the one I'm interested in (call it NodeResults):

```
Public Class Node
    Inherits ObservableValidatableModelBase
        Public Property NodeResults as NodeResults
            Set
                SetAndNotify(_nodeResults, Value) ' INotifyPropertyChanged
            AddHandler _nodeResults.ErrorsChanged, AddressOf BubbleErrorsChanged ' INotifyDataErrorInfo?
             End Set
        End Property
        ' etc.
```

and `NodeResults`:

```
Public Class NodeResults
    Inherits ObservableValidatableModelBase

        ' many properties here, each validated using custom Data Annotations. This works, when I bind a text box directly to here, for example.
```

`ObservableValidatableModelBase`Implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, and stores its errors in a collection called `errors`:

```
Private errors As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))()
Public ReadOnly Property HasErrors As Boolean Implements INotifyDataErrorInfo.HasErrors
    Get
        Return errors.Any(Function(e) e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Value.Count > 0)
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetErrors(propertyName As String) As IEnumerable Implements INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors
    Try
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) Then
            If If(errors?.Keys?.Contains(propertyName), False) _
                AndAlso If(errors(propertyName)?.Count > 0, False) Then ' if there are any errors, defaulting to false if null
                Return errors(propertyName)?.ToList() ' or Nothing if there are none.
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Else
            Return errors.SelectMany(Function(e) e.Value.ToList())
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New List(Of String)({"Error getting errors for validation: " & ex.Message})
    End Try
End Function

Public Event ErrorsChanged As EventHandler(Of DataErrorsChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged

Public Sub NotifyErrorsChanged(propertyName As String)
    ErrorsChangedEvent?.Invoke(Me, New DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Sub BubbleErrorsChanged(sender As Object, e As DataErrorsChangedEventArgs)
    If TypeOf (sender) Is ObservableValidatableModelBase Then
        errors = DirectCast(sender, ObservableValidatableModelBase).errors
    End If
    NotifyErrorsChanged(String.Empty)
End Sub
```

What I want to happen is for the individual `Node`s in the `CollectionView` to notify the `ListView`, so that it highlights the individual entries that are invalid (i.e. have a `NodeResults` that is invalid) on the screen.

My first instinct is that Node somehow needs to subscribe to and bubble the `NodeResults`' `ErrorsChanged` event, hence the `BubbleErrorsChanged` method on the `ObservableValidatableModelBase` class - but that doesn't seem to work.

Another possibility is - does ListView even have a default template for displaying validation exceptions? If not, should something like this work? (it doesn't...)

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem, Converter={StaticResource ValidationExceptionToColourConverter}}"/>
     </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Where `ValidationExceptionToColourConverter` simply returns Brushes.Red or Brushes.White depending on whether the error is `Nothing` or not.

Note: Binding a text box directly to Nodes.NodeResults.SomeProperty works fine, giving the results I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the following:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=HasErrors, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBrushConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```